# how to link pages depending on foreign key using django

Tags: django, database, hyperlink, foreign-keys

I tried to link countries to continents depending on the foreign key "ckey". I tried using filter and .raw but it didn't work. I tried to use it directly on HTML but it said it cannot praise it. I need to know if there is another way of linking pages like "continents -> countries -> cities -> ...." using Django.

**models**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Continents(models.Model):
    ckey = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    continentName = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class country(models.Model):
    countryNum = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    countryName = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    countryBrief= models.TextField(max_length=500)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    cost = models.FloatField(max_length=10)
    cultures = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    rulesBrief = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    location = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    ckey = models.ForeignKey('Continents', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Continents, country

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request,"guide/home.html")

def continents(request):
    continentdata = Continents.objects.all()
    return render(request,"guide/Continents.html",{'Continents':continentdata})

def countrylist(request):
    countries = country.objects.all()
    first_person = country.objects.filter(ckey='as45914')
    context = {
        "first_person":first_person,
        "countries":countries,
    }
    return render(request,"guide/countrylist.html",context=context)
```

**html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{first_person}}
</body>
</html>
```

[strange message I got when I run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw5QN.png)

How do I link pages like that? For example "Europe > United kingdom > all cities under UK London ..." using Django. I know how to do it in general, all countries > all cities, but not in that way.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [mre] [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1):

```py
# Get list by Obj
continentObj = Continents.objects.get(ckey='as45914')
countryList = Country.objects.filter(ckey=cObj)

# Get List by Related Attribute
countryList = Country.objects.filter(ckey__ckey='as45914')
```

---

### edit

@OP pretty much you'd use related Attributes.

Lets say you had three models

```py
class Continents():
    name = charfield

class Country():
    continents = Key(Continents)

class City():
    country = Key(Country)
```

Now how to get all Cities in Europe

```py
list_Of_Cities = City.objects.filter(country__continents__name='Europe')
```

---

#### edit 2

Per your last comment, you got a Queryset from the filter (which is correct!)

If you know the Filter will always return 1 item use:

- `obj = country.objects.filter(field=value).first()` - Grab the first (will be None if there's no matches)
- `obj = country.objects.get(field=value)` - Get 1 (will crash if query returns zero or more than 1!)

From there you just do `obj.countryName`

But If the filter can return Multiple matches, here are some ways to get the values:

```py
# QuerySet
# qs = <QuerySet [<country: country object (973)>]>

# Way 1:
names = qs.values('countryName')
# names = [{'countryName': '{name1}'}, {'countryName': '{name2}'},]
#   (Array of Dicts)


# Way 2:
names = qs.values_list('countryName')
# names = [('{name1}'), ('{name2}'),]
#   (Array of Tuples)


# Way 3:
names = qs.values_list('countryName', flat=True)
# names = ['{name1}', '{name2}',]
#   (Array of Names)


# Way 4: (Just loop)
for i in qs:
    i.countryName
```

Comment: [answer] [Help] Code-only answers are poor, please say why this answers the question. Comments re the question belong in comments on the question, not in posts.

Comment: @user19272052 no problem, ty for fixing it. So basically the first code block shows you how to filter based on the foreign key, I assume the duplicate `ckey` column threw you off and you just needed a little nudge. I've further explained the concept in my edit

Comment: @Nealium I understand now how to get to that city but I get a problem I think it's related to the key when I run the server I got a query instead of a name  <QuerySet [<country: country object (973)>]>

Comment: @user19272052 a bit late, but if you're still having troubles I edited my Answer. the Tldr is use a `filter().first()` or a `get()` - filter's always returns a **List** of Objects, either specify to get a single object or there's ways to fetch values out of the QS (code block)

Answer (score 0):

**for viwes**

```
def countrylist(request):
    list_Of_Cities = country.objects.filter(ckey__ckey='as45914').values('countryName')

    context = {
         "list_Of_Cities":list_Of_Cities
  }
    return render(request,"guide/countrylist.html",context=context)
```

***and in HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    {% for i in list_Of_Cities %}
    {{i.countryName}}
    {% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```